# Laravel onDelete('cascade') works, except on one relationship

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, cascade

Most of the `onDelete('cascade')` logic works. I'm using MySQL, database engine is innoDB, Laravel version is 5.5.

- Deleting a comment will delete its replies.
- Deleting a post will delete its comments and replies.
- Deleting a user will delete its posts and replies... *but NOT its comments*.

This is how my **comments migration** looks like:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Which is pretty much like my **replies migration**, so not sure why it's not working properly...

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('replies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('comment_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('comment_id')->references('id')->on('comments')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

These are how my models look like:

**User model**

```php
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Reply::class);
}
```

**Comment model**

```php
public function post() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Reply::class);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been at this already for the whole day, but I can't figure it out. Would really appreciate any help you can give me.

I'm new to this, and this part (databases) is especially a weak point of mine.

### **UPDATE:** Posts migration

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Then I added this migration:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->change();
    });
    Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Anything wrong here?

Comment: Jonas Staudenmeir, thank you for the edit! How did you do that?

Comment: Take a look at the `side-by-side markdown` view: I added `<!-- language-all: php -->`.

Comment: Is there an error? Or are the comments just not deleted?

Comment: Is the comments table innodb?

Comment: No, there is no error. It's just that the comment are not deleted.
Yup, comments table are innodb.


...Well, ok, there is one, but not a database error. The only error that occurs is when I load up the comments list page in Admin, where Admin can view all comments. It's looking for comments->user()->name, but since the user was deleted, it throws an error.

Comment: And thanks, will use `<!-- language-all: php -->` next time!

Comment: Please add the `posts` migration.

Comment: Added post migrations earlier today. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your migrations work for me. Are all the foreign key constraints correctly set in the database? Try reproducing the issue on an empty database.

Comment: The other day, on a live test site, after changing the database engine to InnoDB (default engine on my web hosting is MyISAM), all `onDelete('cascade')` wasn't working! But after refreshing the migrations, everything worked perfectly. Will try doing the same thing on my local copy, which is where this issue is happening. But anyway, thanks for looking into this Jonas, I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work like that. When you create a foreign key on a `MyISAM` table, it just gets silently ignored. When you then convert the table to `InnoDB`, MySQL doesn't know about the previously failed foreign key.